# Why does my left div align to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Consider:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .left, .right {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 49%;
        }
        .left {
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        .right {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because inline elements are vertically aligned to the baseline by default. You need to change that.

```
.left, .right { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: No, that should be set on their parent, IIRC.

Comment: That hasn't worked for me in most cases. This has. (The only exception I make is for `<th>` and `<td>` elements.)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `display:inline-block;`. So all elements align corresponding to the given vertical alignment.

You could do `.left, .right { vertical-align: top; }`.

Or just float your boxes:

`.left, .right { float:left; display:block; }`

It would be better for [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer).

Comment: Floated elements are better with `display: inline` as it avoids the IE double margin bug.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `display:inline-block;`

```css
.left {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: We've already answered with the same solution. Why do you bother posting a redundant answer yourself?